# Can my car be hacked?

Tags: attack-prevention, vulnerability

I was reading [this article](http://www.wired.com/2015/07/hackers-remotely-kill-jeep-highway) about car hacking and the fact that there are a half million vulnerable cars scared the living daylights out of me!

I did some research and many sources claim that car hacking is **Nearly Impossible**, but if you see that from the other side, the Nearly Impossible is still **Possible**.

I understand that connected cars are only part of the larger “Internet of things” movement, in which more everyday objects are being made capable of getting online, okay that's the future but not when people's lives are in the balance.

How hard is it to hack a car and is it secure to buy a connected car?

Comment: Depends what you want to do - if you have keyless entry and start, it might be as easy as amplifying the signal from the key to the car. If you want to mess with the audio system, look for Bluetooth flaws. If you want to make the engine management system seize up, plug into the CANBUS and fuzz it. Remotely, it depends what the designers allowed the network to communicate with. As it stands, this question is probably a bit broad, as a result.

Comment: Easy step to an unhackable car, go buy a car from the sixties.

Comment: It is not impossible, but it is still extremely difficult as the malware has to be designed specifically for that car and be based on the original, reverse-engineered firmware. This is even more difficult than malicious firmware on computers, and even those aren't (yet) common.

Comment: You have good timing: the FBI (in concert with other federal agencies) just issued an advisory today about auto hacking attacks. This Wired article reports on that warning and also contains some good links & explanation about the broader range of attack vectors that afflict auto security:  http://www.wired.com/2016/03/fbi-warns-car-hacking-real-risk/

Answer (score 1):

Answering title question: YES

Of course, this only really applies to cars with remotely-accessible electronic systems. So, most vehicles made before the turn of the millennium are probably safe in this regard. However, there are other ways to electronically "hack" a car if the attacker has physical access too.

Answer to "how hard is it": It depends

This goes for any broad category of applications - not just cars. It all depends on exactly how the software was written, what safeguards are in place, and how competent the people maintaining the code are. It also depends a lot on the competency and resources of the attacker.

Much of the answer to this question won't really be certain until someone discovers and discloses a vulnerability in the system. But then, of course, it's too late. You can only hope that the manufacturer of the system built in enough effective security to ensure that it will be a long time before any worthwhile and exploitable vulnerabilities are found.